# Node Child Process (Spawn) is not returning data correctly when using with function

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, function, spawn

I am trying to generate a new score based on the output of my python script.
The python script returning the data correctly and JS program printing correctly
but the problem is when i return the value and print it, it shows undefined

Function Code -

```
async function generateCanadaScore(creditscore = 0) {
  console.log(creditscore, "creditscore"); //prints 300
  let MexicoData = 0;
  const python = spawn("python", [
    "cp_production.py",
    "sample_dill.pkl",
    "mexico",
    Number(creditscore),
  ]);

  await python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
    console.log(data.toString()); //prints number 
    MexicoData = data.toString();
    console.log(MexicoData) // prints number
//working fine till here printing MexicoData Correctly (Output from py file) , problem in return
    return MexicoData ;
  });
  python.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data); // this function doesn't run
  });
// return MexicoData ; already tried by adding return statement here still same error
}
```

Calling Function Code -

```
app.listen(3005, async () => {
  console.log("server is started");
  //function calling 
  // Only for testing purpose in listen function 
  let data = await generateCanadaScore(300);
  console.log(data, "data"); // undefined
});
```

I will not be able to share python code it is confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `await` on the event handler. (It returns `undefined`, so you're basically doing `await Promise.resolve(undefined)`, which waits for nothing).

You might want to wrap your child process management using `new Promise()` (which you'll need since `child_process` is a callback-async API, and you need promise-async APIs):

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process");

function getChildProcessOutput(program, args = []) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buf = "";
    const child = spawn(program, args);

    child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      buf += data;
    });

    child.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        return reject(`${program} died with ${code}`);
      }
      resolve(buf);
    });
  });
}

async function generateCanadaScore(creditscore = 0) {
  const output = await getChildProcessOutput("python", [
    "cp_production.py",
    "sample_dill.pkl",
    "mexico",
    Number(creditscore),
  ]);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Still not working checkout this screenshot printing blank [Image](https://paste.pics/a05614d6ed1763b8c8baa19d83a81de7) .PS -  generateCanadaScore function output const printing data correctly

Comment: @Vaibhavdadhich make sure to accept his answer if it helped you, so others know that it's a viable solution for similar issues.

Comment: You're not showing any code that would hook up the function to a request handler, you're just calling it once after the app starts. I doubt that's what you'd want for an API.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKX It worked  when hooked with request handler , now out of curiosity my question is why it was not working when using with app.listen ?

Comment: Because the app.listen callback is just for knowing when the app is listening, nothing more.